# Simple SignalR Android Example Issue

Tags: android, azure, websocket, signalr, signalr-hub

I am basically trying to send a message from my android to my server and the server to send back a response to my android app. I followed [THIS tutorial](https://whathecode.wordpress.com/2014/03/20/getting-started-with-the-java-signalr-sdk/#comment-4639).

Just a simple exercise to introduce myself in to SignalR using Azure Web API and Android.

**My Complete Server code in C#:**

```
   public class TestHub: Hub {
        public void SendMessage(string name, string message) {
            // Call the broadcastMessage method to update clients.
            Clients.All.broadcastMessage(name, message);
        }
        public void SendClientMessage(CustomType obj) {
            Clients.All.broadcastMessage("From Server", "Server got the message bro");
        }
        public class CustomType {
            public string Name;
            public int Id;
        }
   }
```

**Complete Android Java code:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Handler handler;
    TextView statustext;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        handler = new Handler();
        statustext = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.status);

        Platform.loadPlatformComponent(new AndroidPlatformComponent());
        // Change to the IP address and matching port of your SignalR server.
        String host = "https://My-Service-name.azure-mobile.net/";
        HubConnection connection = new HubConnection(host);
        HubProxy hub = connection.createHubProxy("TestHub");
        SignalRFuture < Void > awaitConnection = connection.start();

        try {
            awaitConnection.get();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {

        } catch (ExecutionException e) {

        }

        hub.subscribe(this);

        try {
            hub.invoke("SendMessage", "Client", "Hello Server!").get();
            hub.invoke("SendClientMessage",
                new CustomType() {
                    {
                        Name = "Android Homie";
                        Id = 42;
                    }
                }).get();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {

        } catch (ExecutionException e) {

        }
    }

    //I have no idea what the following method is for. Just followed the tutorial.. (blindly)
    public void UpdateStatus(String status) {
        final String fStatus = status;
        handler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                statustext.setText(fStatus);
            }
        });
    }

    public class CustomType {
        public String Name;
        public int Id;
    }
}
```

**Problems with this:**

**1. I get an exception:**

> java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
>   microsoft.aspnet.signalr.client.transport.NegotiationException: There
>   was a problem in the negotiation with the server

**2. I feel like I haven't properly called the server from the Java code.**
  Should the URL be:

> https://My-Service-name.azure-mobile.net/

or

> https://My-Service-name.azure-mobile.net/api/signalr

Can someone clarify these doubts and help me set it up?